# How can I send the user to a different page based on a boolean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a webapp that is a typical post-redirect-get pattern. The app has a well defined start and finish.

Once a user is finished, their session is not immediately expired, but they are "done" as far as the application is concerned. They should be able to refresh the final page of the app and interact with it as they see fit.

They should not, however, be able to change the URL or hit the back button to go back at this point.

This can easily be solved by setting a boolean in the session. Let's say `sessionComplete = true`.

Now, when the user hits back or tries to manually hit another URL, if `sessionComplete == true`, they should just be re-directed back to final page of the application and the controllers of the other pages should never be hit.

The only difference should be this redirect. Every other part of the app should execute as usual. How can I do this in Spring?

Comment: Use a Filter to interrogate the the session and redirect as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a filter with a pattern `*` (all requests) fits fairly well to your situation. A `doFilter` method might have a look:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // obtaining a sessionComplete value
    Object value = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("sessionComplete");
    boolean sessionComplete = Boolean.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(value).toString());

    // go to the final page
    if (sessionComplete) {
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("locationToRedirect");
    }

    // otherwise, pass a control to controllers
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this will do what's intended.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, you may try it, if there are any questions, I will be glad to reply

Comment: So I think this would have worked, but I ended up having to do this with a Spring interceptor. I think one of our proprietary libraries was causing problems. The concept is the same, anyway.